# how to import data (instances) into an existing ontology in protoge

Tags: ontology, protege, ifc

Can anyone tell me the steps that are required to populate an Ontology?

I have created a domain-specific Ontology (TBox = Terminological knowledge) which consists of defined classes and relations.
On the other hand, I have an IFC file (The Industry Foundation Classes) which has the instances.
I have converted the IFC file to IFC OWL and have understood that I need to map the classes into the newly created ontology.
However, I don't understand how I can get the instances of the associated classes and relations into my created ontology.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming

Comment: The tags that I have used for the Question are provided from Stackoverflow, and there are several questions posted on this, OWL is part of semantic web technologies and what I need is related to programming that is JAVA based or written with Python from what I have come across up to now.How ever I am hoping if there is any inbuilt support from protoge or the OWL API that is already developed by others in community,thanks

Comment: I believe this question is adequate for stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You have created two ontology files, one with the tbox and one with the abox. Usually, in this scenario the abox would use an owl:imports annotation to refer to the tbox, and would not, itself, need class declarations - it would use the IRIs for the classes already declared in the tbox. In protégé, creating an imports is straightforward.

A common issue is incorrect IRIs: if you've created your abox without initially importing the tbox, it's possible the classes you used do not match the tbox classes (e.g., the abox classes use the abox IRI as their base IRI instead of the tbox).

Comment: Thank you for your comment Ignazio, The IRI's and corresponding classes names of TBox and ABox are different (The Abox was initially written in EXPRESS schema and then converted to ifcOWL), does that mean should I first add and map the classes of ABOX prior to Direct import in the protégé?

Comment: You could add a mapping between the classes or directly edit the abox to match your needs, the two approaches are equivalent - whichever is best for you will do